# How to correctly define in response.css and yield in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and there is one thing I was trying for two days but still not succeed.
I am practicing to extract information of football players listed in https://sofifa.com/. I adopted the code sample from https://docs.scrapy.org/ and edit it as below. The information I am practicing to extract is OVA.

Does anyone know how should I correctly define the element of "span.something..." in the code below?

Many thanks,
James

```
import scrapy
class ToScrapeCSSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "player-css"
    start_urls = [
        'https://sofifa.com/players?type=all&tm%5B0%5D=1&r=210024&set=true',
    ]

    **def parse(self, response):
        for playerInfor in response.css("div.card"):
            yield {**
                **'OVA': playerInfor.css("span.bp3-tag p::bp3-tag p").extract()**
            }

        next_page_url = response.css("li.next > a::attr(href)").extract_first()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this css selector `response.css("tbody.list")` instead of `response.css("div.card")`

for the `response.css("tbody.list")`  data is easy to extract but when i use `response.css("div.card")`  result was some empty list with expected output.

```
for playerInfor in response.css("tbody.list"):
     print( playerInfor.css('td.col.col-oa.col-sort span::text').getall())
```

## output

> ['87', '84', '84', '82', '80', '80', '80', '80', '79', '79', '79', '79', '79', '78', '77', '77', '77', '76', '76', '76', '75', '75', '74', '74', '73', '72', '72', '70', '62', '62', '60', '58', '56']

another approach

```
def parse(self, response):
        mydata =response.css('tbody.list td.col.col-oa.col-sort span::text').extract()
        yield {
            "OVA":mydata
        }
```

#output of mydata

> ['87', '84', '84', '82', '80', '80', '80', '80', '79', '79', '79', '79', '79', '78', '77', '77', '77', '76', '76', '76', '75', '75', '74', '74', '73', '72', '72', '70', '62', '62', '60', '58', '56']

Comment: Hi. It is brilliant. You save my days. I will follow your instruction and try with other data in this website too.

Comment: Hi, I have tried exactly the same as you guided. I could extract some data. However, some of them seem not to be accessable. For example, when I tried with : playerInfor.css("td.col.col-lo span ::text").extract()    , this value will not be extracted. I am unsure if this value is not accessable or I am doing anything wrong. Its format is very similar to the other. Would you please help me to have a quick look on it? Many thanks.

Comment: which column do you want to extract?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your advice. I tried with a new URL and it works great now ^_^. Apologies, this is my second post in this forum so I did not know that there is an accept button. I did it already. All the best.